# How to Remove Google Maps History Icons?

Tags: google-maps

Over the years, I have often searched places on Google Maps. Often, but not always, my searches leave a mark on the map. How do I remove such markings?

I already tried deleting my Google Maps activity history.

[image: Annoying Marking]

Comment: @pnuts Yes, that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Are these locations in your Contacts, perhaps?

Comment: @ale No, they are not. I just searched for them years ago.