# How to remove labels for places that I’ve viewed or searched for on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

If I view a place either by zooming in and clicking on it or searching for this place, it starts to show on the map constantly, even when the map is zoomed in a lot less than how close it would have to be zoomed for this place to appear if I haven’t viewed it in the past.

This is sort of annoying and even a little bit privacy invading, since other people may be looking behind my shoulder, so they know what places I have viewed with Google Maps.

Signed in, a label for Starbucks is displayed:

[image: Screenshot]

Not signed in, the label is not displayed

[image: Screenshot]

Anyway, can I disable the feature and/or remove all of these labels?

Comment: Same question: [How to Remove Google Maps History Icons?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105453/how-to-remove-google-maps-history-icons)

Answer (score -1):

hit those **3 dots** and select **Edit list**

[image]

Comment: This list is empty.